# symfony2 form not rendering password correctly

Tags: php, symfony

I have a 2-step form that asks for a user signup. Here's some code:

```
public function earlySignupAction(Request $request)
    {
        $user = new User();

        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($user)
            ->add('username', 'text')
            ->add('email', 'email')
            ->add('password', 'password')
            ->getForm();

        $form->bind($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
            $userRepository = $em->getRepository('MySiteUserBundle:User');
            $userFoundByUsername = $userRepository->findOneBy(array('username' => $user->getUsername()));

            if ($userFoundByUsername) {
                $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('notice', "Already registered!\n We will notify you soon!");
            } 

            $additionalInfoForm = $this->createForm(new UserType(), $user, array(
                'mode' => 'additional_signup_info'
            ));

            return $this->render('MySiteMainBundle:Signup:index.html.twig',  array(
                'additionalInfoForm' => $additionalInfoForm->createView()));
        }else{
            foreach($form->getErrors() as $key => $error){
                $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('error', $error->getMessage());
            }    
        }

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('MySiteMainBundle_signup_fail'));
    }
```

Now what I want/what should happen is that on the 2nd form (`$additionaInfoForm`) the password field will be pre-populated from the password that was entered on `$form`, but i fact it wasn't. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

The field type password has an attribute, **always_empty** which defaults to true.  Per the docs:

> If set to true, the field will always render blank, even if the
>   corresponding field has a value. When set to false, the password field
>   will be rendered with the value attribute set to its true value. Put
>   simply, if for some reason you want to render your password field with
>   the password value already entered into the box, set this to false.

So you would change:

```
->add('password', 'password')
```

to

```
->add('password', 'password', array('always_empty' => false))
```

Comment: The always_empty option is not working for me either.

Comment: Same for me anyone knows why ?

Comment: If you look at `Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType`, you'll see that when the form is not submitted, the value will be cleared anyway. If setting `always_empty` to false, you'll only see the password show up in case of form validation error (given you're rendering the page   after a POST without redirecting, which you should do when the form is invalid).